# Swift show currency US$ without US

Tags: swift, formatting, locale

I have the following function to format balance

```
private func getFormattedBalance(balance: String, currency: String) -> String {
    if let decimal = Decimal(string: balance) {
        let currencyStyle: Decimal.FormatStyle.Currency = .init(code: currency, locale: Locale.current)
        
        return decimal.formatted(currencyStyle)
    }

    return ""
}
```

The problem is because I am using `Locale.current` instead of `Locale` for the currency I am getting `US$` instead of just `$`. How can I get only the $ symbol but keep the current local(not like this `Locale(identifier: currency)`)?
[image]

Comment: You should respect the locale settings

Comment: Btw If you really want to change how the currency should be displayed only for `USD` just manipulate your string to replace `"US$"` with `"$"`. Note that not all locales will display `"US$"`. `decimal.formatted(currencyStyle).replacingOccurrences(of: "US$", with: "$")`

Comment: Which locale is giving you "502,28 US$" ?

Comment: It is an Austrian region. The problem is I would also need to do the same for CA$ and probably some other currencies. So there is no option to show a short form so to say?

Comment: Just use a regex instead

Comment: I am not sure I can cover all the cases using a regex

Comment: `replacingOccurrences(of: #"[a-zA-Z]+\$"#, with: "$", options: .regularExpression)`

Comment: Well As I said you should respect the locale settings. If you don't even know what you might be dealing with better to do not change it.

Comment: You can also just simply remove all non currency symbols from your string

Comment: `filter { "0"..."9" ~= $0 || $0.isSymbol || $0.isPunctuation }` should work for what you are trying to achieve

Comment: thanks, I guess the second option is better. I guess there are other currencies other than $ with the same issue.

Comment: Maybe even easier would be just filtering non letters `filter { !$0.isLetter }` that would keep spaces as well

Comment: @LeoDabus the 2 and 3 options are not good for example for CHF (Switzerland). iOS uses not a symbol, but text for it.

Comment: As I said you would need to test all locale/currencies. IMO you should leave it with the default format.

Comment: ok, got it . thanks